# Generating a successive code with numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm working with javascript and mongoDB, and I need to generate a specific code for each new mongoDB document :
For Example the first Document will have this code A 0001 RB the second A 0002 RB 
and so on.The first part can go from A to ZZZ and the second from 0001 to 9999. 
I'll be thankfull for any advice.

Comment: This would be a pretty simple task if you write a function that takes the previous code, and increments it; returning the new code. What's your question specifically?

Comment: Actually I have no idea yet !

Comment: @Carcigenicate Actually i want to know how can i increment the previous code.

Comment: Pretend you're not using letters for a second. If I gave you a 9 (base-10), how would you increment it? Think that through. Your question is basically how to increment a base-35 number (numbers 0-9, + all the letters of the alphabet = 35). Figure out how to increment normal base-10 numbers, then generalize that.

Comment: Whoops, your code is actually in two parts. The second part is easy since it's just normal numbers. You can increment them by just adding 1. For the first part though, you have a base-26 number (not 35 like my above comment says). Again, think about how you'd increment normal numbers, then think about how you can apply that to letters representing numbers.

Comment: Hint: converting the number to a String can make this much easier to deal with, although it can be slow.

Comment: And if I use ASCII codes

Comment: @sana what about ASCII?